# jQuery Mobile Multiple Filter Methods - text/input and select/drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, filter

I am creating an Android and iOS app using jQuery and Phonegap with a section intended to help users find map pins to locations in Japan. These pins are divided into categories and sub-categories (e.g. US Bases >> Army, Navy, Marine, or Air Force). I would like to provide users a screen with the ability to filter using the pins in a `listview` by the regular text input field AND a select/drop-down menu (see the image below; the relevant code is also provided at the end of this post).

A screenshot can be found here: http://jefflofting.com/zamavcf/screenshot.png

I would LOVE users to be able to filter by EITHER keyword (text field) OR by category (drop-down).  However, it APPEARS that `data-input:` will only allow for one for filter ID to be entered.

Do I have any options??  Something else that I've considered is making the filter use the text field and setting up the drop-down to automatically input t value of the selected option into that field to make it filter. Though I've found a variation using checkboxes and have successfully made the checkbox selection input into the text field, it doesn't initiate the filter...it just places the value in the field. My Javascript skills are just not at all at the level to switch the Javascript to a select menu and to solve the non-filtering problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="contactdetailstitle">SEARCH BY KEYWORD</div>
<!--Filter by text field-->
<form class="ui-filterable" style="margin-top:-25px;">
    <input id="filterBasic-pinsword" data-type="search" placeholder="search by keyword" name="filterBasic-pinsword">
</form>
<div class="contactdetailstitle" style="margin-top:10px;">SEARCH BY CATEGORY</div>
<!--Filter by drop-down-->
<form style="margin-top:-6px; margin-bottom:25px;">
    <select id="filterBasic-pinscat" data-native-menu="false" name="filterBasic-pinsword">  
        <option class="filterbycat" value=" ">Show All Categories</option>
        <option value="Family Parks">Family Parks</option>
        <option value="Theme Parks">Theme Parks</option>
    </select>
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="false" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-pinscat">
    <li data-icon="false" data-filtertext="Family Parks"><a href="#">We Are Family Park</a></li>
    <li data-icon="false" data-filtertext="Theme Parks"><a href="#">The Cosplay Park</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy method is to search through Keywords and hide anything that doesn't match.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/tk27L2es/

**Example list items** within the span we insert keywords, we also hide these from view

```
<li><span id="hide">themepark</span>Galaxyland</li>
<li><span id="hide">themepark</span>Playland</li>
<li><span id="hide">themepark</span>Magic Mountain Water Park</li>
<li><span id="hide">familypark canada</span>Canada's Wonderland</li>
<li><span id="hide">familypark renfrew</span>Storyland</li>
```

we also create another list for the user to choose the Keyword that would like to search for

```
    <li id="all">All</li>
    <li id="themeparks">Theme Parks</li>
    <li id="familyparks">Family Parks</li>
    <li id="renfrew">Renfrew Theme Parks</li>
    <li id="canada">Canada Theme Parks</li>
```

**css**

```
#hide {
display:none;
}
```

**Jquery** Upon choice of keyword, match keyword and remove the rest from the list

```
var cat;

$(document).on("click", "#cats >li", function (event, ui) {
    cat = $(this).closest("li").attr('id');

    if (cat == "all") {
        $('#filterlist li').show();
    } else {
        $('#filterlist li:contains(' + cat + ')').show();
        $('#filterlist li:not(:contains(' + cat + '))').hide();
    }

    $("#mylistitems").collapsible("collapse");
});
```

ideally if you have a lot of items you want to minimize data in the HTML document so for the keywords you would assign a letter and a number and match items on those.

eg

A1 = Theme Parks

A2 = Family Parks ... and so on

For Updating the choice header dynamically upon click, inspecting the element in a browser will show that JQM has inserted it into `<a>` tags with a class of **ui-collapsible-heading-toggle**

[image]

so an easy way to dynamically change the heading is to grab the text from the list choice item and insert it to the header using that class.

```
ch  = $(this).closest("li").text()  
$(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").text(ch)
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/986q9fy4/

For a dropdown you would use pretty much the same code but with an -- on change -- event and then grabbing the value of the option you select

```
var cat;

$(document).on("change", "#cats", function (event, ui) {

    cat = $("#cats").val();

    if (cat == "all") {
        $('#filterlist li').show();
    } else {
        $('#filterlist li:contains(' + cat + ')').show();
        $('#filterlist li:not(:contains(' + cat + '))').hide();
    }

    $("#mylistitems").collapsible("collapse");
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/9ga9v8py/

Comment: Tasos, thank you SO much for your help!  That almost did it!  The ONLY thing that was different than what I was hoping for is that your example provided a collapsible rather than a drop-down/select.  The issue with the collapsible is that once a category select is made, the category doesn't appear in the  element like a drop-down/select element would to show the user what category filter they're currently using.  Is there ANY way that I could replace your collapsible with the drop-down/select???  Thanks again!

Comment: @jbuman22 yeah you are right, its a drop down you have in you question. Anyway i sorted the heading to update dynamically for the collapsible and created a demo for a drop-down.

Comment: Tasos, if I could trouble you one more time, I have a couple quick questions.  B/c the lists being filtered are quite long, I have `data-autodividers` set as `true`. But, I lose list dividers once I filter based on category. Is there a way to keep list dividers upon filtering??  

The other issue is with using category and keyword filters on multiple pages. When I navigate from `index.html` page, no other category filters work.  The only way I got it to work is by making the `href` `rel=external` b/c it refreshes the page, but makes header/footer disappear each navigation. Thx in advance!

Comment: The autodividers are hiding because they are not matching anything. to get around it you need to create your own list dividers demo. http://jsfiddle.net/yy7037mg/. if you have a lot items consider using a database, it can get the job done easier. -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCIdKSeRD-E  -- i'm not sure about the issue when navigating pages. try putting the script inside the pages